# Prevent VM Persistence 

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am setting up Ubuntu in Virtualbox to test tutorials that I'm making. Each time I boot Ubuntu I need a fresh image, without any saved changes that were previously made (Saved documents or installed programs should not persist).

How can I ensure that no changes persist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the VM into the state you want it in, then create a snapshot.  Restore to that snapshot just before each time you start the VM.  You may be able to automate this with the `vboxmanage snapshot ...` command: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html.  It appears to have a `restore` subcommand, so you may be able script the combined restore + start by also using the `startvm` subcommand.